# UnsatisfiedLinkError for com.aldebaran.qi

Tags: android, nao-robot

I am building an Android app to communicate with a NAO robot so I downloaded the naoqi jar library and added it to my project.

I downloaded the JAR library from the following link:

https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25-downloads-linux

After that I tried running the code from the link

https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-java/blob/master/examples/android/RobotTalk/src/com/aldebaran/HelloAndroidActivity.java

The JAR library is included within build.gradle like follows

Hello
An additional information on how the JAR file is included within build.grade

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation files('libs\\java-naoqi-sdk-2.5.6.5-linux64 (1).jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

I made some changes on the code to look as the following:

```
package samerrihawi.com.naoapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.aldebaran.qi.AnyObject;
import com.aldebaran.qi.CallError;
import com.aldebaran.qi.Session;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Session session = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final EditText mEdit     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editIP);
        final EditText EditPort  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPort);
        final EditText editSentences = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String url = "tcp://" + mEdit.getText().toString() + ":" + EditPort.getText().toString();
                Log.v("com.aldebaran.RobotTalk.connectSD", "Connecting to " + url);

                session = new Session();
                try
                {
                    session.connect(url).sync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    Log.v("com.aldebaran.RobotTalk.connectSD", "Connection Error : " + e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                Log.v("com.aldebaran.RobotTalk.connectSD", "Trying to get a proxy on serviceTest");
                AnyObject proxy;
                try {
                    proxy = session.service("ALTextToSpeech");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot get proxy on ALTextToSpeech", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    Log.v("com.aldebaran.RobotTalk.connectSD", "Failure ! Cannot get proxy on ALTextToSpeech");
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    Log.v("com.aldebaran.RobotTalk.connectSD", "Saying : " + editSentences.getText().toString());
                    proxy.call("say", editSentences.getText().toString());
                } catch (CallError e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }

                Log.v("com.aldebaran.RobotTalk.connectSD", "Done");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And after some trial and error, I found out that the program throws the exception when creating a new object from Session in the following line:

```java
session=new Session();
```

And I am getting the following stacktrace exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: samerrihawi.com.naoapplication, PID: 13347
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/samerrihawi.com.naoapplication-TccpRt1-40ybe5SafG2Riw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/samerrihawi.com.naoapplication-TccpRt1-40ybe5SafG2Riw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.aldebaran.qi.EmbeddedTools.loadEmbeddedLibraries(EmbeddedTools.java:117)
        at com.aldebaran.qi.Session.<clinit>(Session.java:16)
        at samerrihawi.com.naoapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The source of the exception is within this part of the code

```
String javaVendor = System.getProperty("java.vendor");
    if (javaVendor.contains("Android"))
    {
      // Using System.loadLibrary will find the libraries automatically depending on the platform,
      // but we still need to load the dependencies manually and in the correct order.
      System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
      System.loadLibrary("qi");
      System.loadLibrary("qimessagingjni");
      System.out.printf("Libraries loaded. from android\n");
    }
```

I am totally new to NAO programming.

So what must I do in this case to solve this issue ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It might help to also add how you're including the JAR (via Gradle?) as that might be relevant, given the error.

Comment: is your project creating gnustl_shared.so for abi x86 architecture file ?

Comment: Hello, I included the JAR file from File -> Project Structure and then added the JAR from the dependencies menu. As for creating gnustl_shared.so for abi x86 architecture file , I don't think that the project creates it. The exception is thrown when creating the Session object.

Answer (score 0):

The .jar you use is not compiled for Android, but for Linux 64:

```
implementation files('libs\\java-naoqi-sdk-2.5.6.5-linux64 (1).jar')
```

Instead, you must either recompile [`libqi-java`](https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-java) for Android, or try using the one provided along the Qi SDK for Pepper:

- add the repository to your root `build.gradle` file:

  ```
   maven {
       url 'http://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
   }
  ```
- add the dependency in your module's `build.gradle` file (for instance `app/build.gradle`)

  ```
   implementation 'com.aldebaran:libqi-java-android:3.1.0'
  ```

However you managed to embed `libqi-java`, do not for get to load the native libraries first by calling, in Java:

```
new EmbeddedTools().loadEmbeddedLibraries();
```

Note that the protocol is not guaranteed compatible with NAOqi 2.5.

Comment: Thanks Victor of your valuable response. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: Hello Victor, I tried your solution and unfortunately I didn't manage to solve the issue as the exception is thrown within this line of code 

new EmbeddedTools().loadEmbeddedLibraries()

Comment: Which solution have you opted for?
Could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Hello Victor, I tried running the example on the following link:

https://github.com/ghostwan/jnao-example

However I tried to execute the code and I got the following stack trace:

    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.aldebaran.qimessaging.Session.qiSessionCreate() (tried Java_com_aldebaran_qimessaging_Session_qiSessionCreate and Java_com_aldebaran_qimessaging_Session_qiSessionCreate__)
        at com.aldebaran.qimessaging.Session.qiSessionCreate(Native Method)


The exception was thrown when creating a new session: session = new Session();

Comment: I used the following library in my code:

jnaoqi-android.jar

Comment: I also tried to add the following code:

EmbeddedTools ebt = new EmbeddedTools();
        File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
        ebt.overrideTempDirectory(cacheDir);
        ebt.loadEmbeddedLibraries();

But I am still facing the same issue

Comment: I do not know what is wrong, and I am not sure if we can trust that .jar file. Did you try with `implementation 'com.aldebaran:libqi-java-android:3.1.0'`?

Comment: I tried to add implementation 'com.aldebaran:libqi-java-android:3.1.0' to build.gradle but it is not found. Also I will be grateful if you can tell me how to install jre on NAO robot as I am totally newbie in it. Thanks a lot for your help